# CSS issue with div wrapping another

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that I cannot manage to wrap my section properly.

I have a div "container" that with a php part is populated by few divs and I don't know how to properly wrap it with the border:solid of my created div.

html/php part

```
<div class = "listaCarrello" id ="listaCarrello "style="display: <?php echo !isset($_GET['riepilogo'])&&isset($_SESSION['username'])? "block":"none"?>">
        <?php
        $isEmpty = true;
        foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $val) {
            $query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM prodotto WHERE IDProdotto = $key");
            if ($query != null) {
                $isEmpty = false;
                $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
                echo "<div class = \"elemCarrello\">";
                echo "<p class=\"nomeCarrello\">" . $row['nomeProdotto'] . "</p>";
                echo "<div class = \"imgCarrello\">";
                echo "<img src = \"img/" . $row['immagine'] . "\" alt=\"" . $row['nomeProdotto'] . "\"height=\"150px\" width=\"150px\">";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class=\"prezzoCarrello\">";
                echo "<p>Prezzo unitario " . $row['prezzo'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p> Quantità: " . $val;
                echo " - Prezzo totale: ";
                echo "€" . $row['prezzo'] * $val . "</p>";
                $totale = $totale + ($row['prezzo'] * $val);
                echo "<p> Modifica la Quantità: ";
                echo "<input type='number' id = 'quantita' name='quantita' value='" . $val . "'>";
                echo "<button onclick='refreshCookie($key, document.getElementById(\"quantita\").value)'>AGGIORNA</button>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<button class='eliminaCarrello' onclick='eliminaCookie($key)' style='background: white'> <img src='img/elimina.png' height='50' width='50'> </button>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        if (!$isEmpty) {
            echo "<div class='checkOut'>";
            echo "<p>Totale: €" . $totale . "</p>";
            echo '<button id="2ndphase" onclick="goToAddress()">AVANTI</button>';
            echo "</div>";

        }
        ?>
```

css part

```
.listaCarrello{
border:solid;
border-color: lightgray;
border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 99%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.elemCarrello{
margin-top: 5px;
width: 99%;
text-align: left;
float:left;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border: solid;
margin-left: 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.nomeCarrello{
padding-left: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.imgCarrello{
float: left;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.eliminaCarrello{
margin-top: -13px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Sorry for my English and I hope that you understood what I am saying.
I have attached a image as an example[image: This is my problem, the grey part need to go under the last box]

Comment: Show us the HTML and CSS code for that section. Looks like floating issues and missing clearfix.

Comment: Could you provide us some code, please? But I think, it's just a problem with inline blocks.

Comment: You should add some CSS and HTML to the question so that we have a better understanding of what is happening. Still I have provided an answer that I think from your description could fix this issue.

Comment: You can add your code on codepen or jsfiddle to let us see it.

Comment: i updated my question sorry if i didn't provide any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the "container" divs overflow styling to auto.

```
container{
   overflow:auto;
}
```